# can't send message from javascript to c# using fleck

Tags: c#, javascript, websocket

So i have a problem. I want to send some message from javascript to my c# server using fleck. I start a server in my app like thease:

```
    var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
        var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8081");
        server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () => allSockets.Add(socket);
            socket.OnClose = () => allSockets.Remove(socket);
            socket.OnMessage = message =>
            {
                foreach (var s in allSockets.ToList())
                    s.Send(message);
            };
        });
```

And on my javascript side i have:

```
   function sendPodatke(){
        document.write('send!');
        socket.send("javascript");
        document.write('aftersend!');
    }

    function connect(){
    document.write('connect!');
      socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');
      socket.onmessage = function(mess) {
        animateCharacter(mess.data);
      };

    };

    connect();
    sendPodatke();
```

So i get write connect!, send! but not afterSend. IOn my c# server i see that connection is done but i newer get a onMessage call..

Any ideas?

thank u all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A websocket handshake is an asynchronous operation.  You can register an `onopen` callback in your client and should only send data from client to server once this runs.  See the [websocket API docs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#the-websocket-interface) for details.